# Xcode: New Storyboard connection

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

After creating a new storyboard i can no longer connect buttons to my .h header file by control dragging from the button to the IBAction- using Xcode 4.3- I get no errors -and I can still connect buttons to my previous storyboard for the iphone, but not for the storyboard for the iPad.

Comment: Click the New storyboard and check in the **identity inspector** for Custom Class Field that it has your **my.h File name** if it is not filled with your my.h file name , then please fill that with your file name and then try your thing

Comment: Thank you ! Can you please post that as an answer? so I cant vote and accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Kindly click your Identity inspector and check the Class type of the Storyboard